# How to handle/enforce single instance threading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a "worker" process that is running constantly on a dedicated server, sending emails, processing data extracts etc.

I want to have all of these processes running asynchronously, but I only want one instance of each process running at any one time. If a process is already running, I don't want to queue up running it again.

[example, simplified]

```
while (true)
{
    // SLEEP HERE

        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DataScheduleWorker.Run());

        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => EmailQueueWorker.Run());
}
```

Basically, I want this entire process to run endlessly, with each of the tasks running parallel to each other, but only one instance of each task running at any point in time.

How can I achieve this in C# 5? What's the cleanest/best way to implement this?

**EDIT**

Would something as simple as this suffice, or would this be deemed bad?:

```
        Task dataScheduleTask = null;

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(600);

            // Data schedule worker

            if (dataScheduleTask != null && dataScheduleTask.IsCompleted) dataScheduleTask = null;
            if (dataScheduleTask == null)
            {
                dataScheduleTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DataScheduleWorker.Run());
            }
        }
```

Comment: i am not quite sure why you are creating threads in the loop instead of reusing workers. you could look into SemaphoreSlim.wait() to block them.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to use tasks in my pseudo code. Updated.
Would SemaphoreSlim.Wait() just queue them up?

Comment: That's called "mutual exclusion" in software engineering.  You use a Mutex for that.  Little point in making it complicated.

Comment: Thanks Hans. My understanding of a Mutex was that it would queue up requests. I'll have another read...

Comment: Unfortunately, according to the MS documentation, they are queued up (as I read it): "If a thread acquires a mutex, the second thread that wants to acquire that mutex is suspended until the first thread releases the mutex.".

Comment: with SemaphoreSlim. you could check if it is running  and only enter the semaphore if the "crossroads" is empty, skipping the creation otherwise. it should be possible to achieve this with mutex too (ok it seems it is not),but if i would start to work on a problem like this  today i would definitely first look at TPL Dataflow like Jon Sket advised. managing multithreading always turns out more intricate than one expects

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a perfect job for either an [actors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) framework, or possibly [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx). Fundamentally you've got one actor (or block) for each job, waiting for messages and processing them independently of the other actors. In either case, your goal should be to write as little of the thread handling and message passing code as possible - ideally none. This problem has already been largely solved; you just need to evaluate the available options and use the best one for your task. I would probably start with Dataflow, personally.